# Does it improve SEO to redirect website search to google search?

Tags: seo

Let's say your website has a search box to search among content of the website.

Is it a good idea to redirect the user with the search query to google, so that he comes to website again from google, to improve your seo?

Answer (score 2):

No, that wouldn't be a ranking factor. Every website would be using that technique if it truly influenced Google's ranking.

Focus on the content itself, it will have a far greater impact on where you rank.